# How do you get python to find specific text in a list and then print it

Tags: python, list

This is what I have so far:

```
def lists():
    global ClientList, highList, moderateList
    ClientList = [    ["NeQua,High"],
                      ["ImKol,Moderate"],
                      ["YoTri,Moderate"],
                      ["RoDen,High"],
                      ["NaThe,Moderate"],
                      ["ReWes,Moderate"],
                      ["BrFre,High"],
                      ["KaDat,High"],
                      ["ViRil,High"],
                      ["TrGeo,High"]]
     highList = ["Running", "Swimming", "Aerobics", "Football", "Tennis"]
     moderateList = ["Walking", "Hicking", "Cleaning", "Skateboarding", "Basketball"]
     checkclient()

def checkclient():
    global ClientList, highList, moderateList
    answer = input("please enter the client ID: ")
    answer2 = next(answer for answer in ClientList)
    print(answer)
```

So I want to input the specific clientID, I want python to then find the client ID in the list, print the clientID with the intensity level (high or moderate) so I can use it later to ask the user how many minutes they spent exercising in the different activities based on whether their intensity was high or moderate.

At the moment the code only prints the first part of the list regardless of what the variable answer is: ["NeQua, High"].

Please can you tell me how to fix this and try to keep it simple as I am relatively new to Python.

Thanks
Cameron

Comment: Please check that the indentation in the question is correct; Python is whitespace sensitive. You can paste *all of your code*, select it and press `{}` button in the toolbar, or `ctrl+k` to make a proper code block.

Comment: `next(answer for answer in ClientList)` will make a generator of each item in `ClientList` and take the first one.  That means that it will always get `["NeQua, High"]`.  I believe what you want instead is to change your `ClientList` to be composed of things like `["NeQua", "High"]` instead of `["NeQua, High"]`.  You could then say `answer2 = next(client for client in ClientList if client[0] == answer)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might change it as follows:

```
def checkclient():
    global ClientList, highList, moderateList
    answer = input("please enter the client ID: ")  # input: NaThe
    try:
        answer2 = next(a for a in ClientList if answer in a) 
    except StopIteration:
        checkclient()
    else:
        print(answer2)  # NaThe,Moderate
```

`next` returns the first element of an iterable so you always get the first element of `ClientList`, so you need to filter out the ones containing your ID.

Comment: `next()` just produces the next element of an iterable. It doesn't care whether the element is truthy or falsey. It might also be cleaner to use an ordinary loop, e.g. `for client in ClientList: if answer in client: print(client)`, rather than creating a new `list` and calling `next()` on it.

Comment: True. Updated answer. Thx for attention!

Comment: Again, it produces the _next_ element. If you keep passing it a fresh iterable, the "next" element will always be the first one. If you want to proceed through an iterable, you have to give it something like a generator.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Say if the user entered in a clientID that wasn't on the list, how would I get it to say it is invalid and ask the user to enter it again?

Comment: Also the raw_input doesn't work, it says that it is not defined. So I changed it to input() is this ok?

Comment: @CameronWard Sure! I added some suggestions how you could handle the case where `next` is called on an empty iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary instead (and there's no need to wrap it in a function that does nothing but create global objects).

```
ClientList = {"NeQua":"High",
              "ImKol":"Moderate",
              "YoTri":"Moderate",
              "RoDen":"High",
              "NaThe":"Moderate",
              "ReWes":"Moderate",
              "BrFre":"High",
              "KaDat":"High",
              "ViRil":"High",
              "TrGeo":"High"}
```

You don't need to specify mutable objects like `list`s or dictionaries as `global` if all you want to do is mutate them. You only need `global` if you want local assignments to the same name to also assign to the global name. More importantly, though, `next()` just returns the next element in an iterable. As a `list` is an ordered sequence, a generator that you make out of it with `answer for answer in ClientList` will have the same order, and the `next()` of that (redundant, I might add) generator will always be the first element of `ClientList`, because you keep making a new generator. If you want `next()` to proceed through the whole thing, you'd have to save it first. However, none of that is necessary here. Just access the dictionary. I use `get()` here to avoid errors if the user tries to access a user that doesn't exist.

```
def checkclient():
    answer = input("please enter the client ID: ")
    print(ClientList.get(answer, 'Not found.'))

checkclient()
```

Also note that a function must be defined *before* it is called (order matters).

Comment: Thanks for your help although I get an error when I run the program: AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'get' Do I need to import something to use the .get command?

Comment: @CameronWard - That error means that you created the object incorrectly. Copy and paste the exact code block I provided, which is a dictionary.

Comment: def checkclient():
    answer = input("please enter the client ID: ")
    print(ClientList.get(answer, 'Not found.'))
And I get the error :AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @CameronWard - Right, because, again, you created the object (`ClientList`) incorrectly. It won't work if you copy it wrong. Note that each line in the code block where I define that object in this answer has two strings separated by a colon. It sounds like you're using another comma rather than a colon, because that's what a `set` would look like.